# Valhalla routing engine with data from postgresql database

Tags: postgresql, routes, openstreetmap, turn-by-turn

i have a postgres database where i have imported a pbf file from https://download.geofabrik.de/ using https://osm2pgsql.org/, i was wondering if it was possible to specify valhalla (https://github.com/valhalla/valhalla) to read routing data from my database instead of specifying the pbf file directly.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Random remark: you can also do routing in-db with [pgrouting](https://docs.pgrouting.org/latest/en/aStar-family.html) or [Apache AGE](https://age.apache.org/age-manual/master/intro/overview.html).

Comment: Thanks for the remark! Do pgrouting or apache age also provide turn-by-turn information? For example if i specify two points on the maps can they provide me the directions needed to go from the starting point to the destination?

Comment: Yes, they both give you an aggregated path from `a` to `b` with aggregated costs, or a step-by-step, vertex-by-vertex, turn-by-turn path with the cost associated with each step. There should be some examples here if you search `pgrouting` and `apache-age` tags.